Probability that a ball was chosen from a specific bag

Each of three bags $A, B, C$ contains white balls and black balls. $A$ has $a_{1}$ white & $b_{1}$ black, $B$ has $a_{2}$ white & $b_{2}$ black and $C$ has $a_{3}$ white & $b_{3}$ black. A ball is drawn at random and is found be white. Find the probability that it is from A.

Since we know that a white ball is drawn. We narrow our sample space to $a_1 +a_2 + a_3$ white balls. Now, probability that a ball came from bag $A$ should be $\frac{a_1}{a_1 +a_2 + a_3}$.
This is wrong and we get a different answer if we use Baye's Theorem. But what is wrong with this approach?

Each white ball in each bag isn't equally likely to be taken. Imagine we had two bags. One with $500$ white balls, and the other with one white ball. We have 50/50 odds of choosing each bag, yet if we choose the first bag each of the $500$ balls are equally likely to be chosen while if we chose the second bag we know which ball we get. In this way, the white ball that is alone is $500$ times more likely to be chosen than any one white ball in the first bag.
A similar argument can be seen in your problem. Every white ball is not equally likely to be chosen, hence $\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}$ is incorrect. Bayes Theorem gives
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}} = \frac{\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}}{ \frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+ \frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}}$$
as the above is the probability that we select a white ball from $A$ divided by the probability of selecting a while ball in general.

You just need to change your formula from
$$\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2+a_3}\;\; to\;\; \frac{f_1}{f_1+f_2+f_3}$$
where $f_1, f_2, f_3$ represent the fraction of white balls in each box instead of their numbers, analogous to a mixture problem.
